# How to display dynamically the previous month name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, string, datetime

I want to display the previous month name. My code is given below but it displays the index of that month. I want the name of that month. 
According to this given code it dipslays the tool tip as "Balance up to 9", but I want to display "Balance up to September".
How get the name of that month?

```
lblPreviousBalance.ToolTip = "Balance up to " + (DateTime.Now.Month - 1);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
string previousMonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("MMMM");
```

If you want it in a specific language, you can pass a `CultureInfo` object to the method:

```
string prevMonthInFrench = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

For more options you can check the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) article at MSDN.

Comment: what is CultureInfo. Is it variable name or something else. If i use the above code then it gives error as CultureInfo does not exit in current context.

Comment: @Shalni: add `using System.Globalization;` to the using directives at the top of your file. In short `CultureInfo` is a class representing a language and region. More info here: [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add in the the answer of @Fredrik Mörk, You can specify the Format without calling `ToString()` method. i.e besides doing this:

```
yourDate.ToString("MMMM")
```

you can also do:

```
yourDate:MMMM
```

Usage:

```
$"Balance Up to {DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1):MMMM}"
```